# Django raise ValueError( ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "Order.variation" must be a "ProductVariation" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Im trying to create a Orderobject but I get this error, and I dont know how to fix

```
   variation_obj = ProductVariation.objects.get(id=int(variation_id_list[index]))
                 quantity = variation_quantity_list[index]
                 total = variation_total_list[index]
                 total = float(total)
                 order_object = Order(user=request.user, variation=variation_obj.id, quantity=quantity, total=total)
```

error:

```
 Django   raise ValueError( ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "Order.variation" must be a "ProductVariation" instance.
```

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):

    variation = models.ForeignKey(ProductVariation,
                                  on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    uploaded_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    total = models.FloatField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
order_object = Order(
    user=request.user, 
    variation=variation_obj, 
    quantity=quantity, 
    total=total
).save()
```

Pass the foreinkey object instead of it's id

Answer (score 1):

For the `variation`, you use the `variation_obj` object, so:

```
order_object = Order(
    user=request.user, variation=variation_obj, quantity=quantity, total=total
)
```